# asp.net chart Onclick Event handlers

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I have an asp.net page with several charts. I would like the user to be able to click a chart, then create a larger view of the chart. I was thinking of just using session state data to populate the chart in a new asp page. However, the event is not firing!

```
<div id="dq_chart_container" style="position:absolute; height:300px; top:35px; width:100%;">
                <asp:Chart ID="DeviceQueries" runat="server" Width="700px" Height="300px" OnClick="DeviceQueries_Click">
                    <ChartAreas>
                        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
                    </ChartAreas>
                </asp:Chart>


protected void DeviceQueries_Click(object sender, ImageMapEvents e)
{
     // check for null sender
     // transfer session state data to another page
     // event doesn't fire!!!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice the caveat in the [Chart click event documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chart.click%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Occurs when the active image map area defined by PostBackValue on the
>   Chart control is clicked.

It's hard to tell from the code you've shown, but if you're just doing a "proof of concept", *you need to make sure there is actual data in the Chart for the click event to work*.  The click is connected to an image map, so the chart image needs to be there for you to click on it.

Check your rendered HTML output (the page source) for the chart to make sure you are getting an image for your chart (that you can click on to fire the event).